# Adding two columns to existing DataFrame using withColumn

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a `DataFrame` with a few columns. Now I want to add two more columns to the existing DataFrame.

Currently I am doing this using `withColumn` method in DataFrame.

**for example:**

```
df.withColumn("newColumn1", udf(col("somecolumn")))
  .withColumn("newColumn2", udf(col("somecolumn")))
```

Actually I can return both newcoOlumn values in single UDF method using Array[String]. But currently this is how I am doing it.

Is there anyway, I can do this effectively? using `explode` is the good option here?

Even if I have to use `explode`,  I have to use `withColumn` once, then return the column value as `Array[String]`, then using `explode`, create two more columns.

Which one is effective? or is there any alternatives?

**Update:**Refer @blert answer, `withColumns` is the way to go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**May 2023**: It's now possible with new `withColumns` (notice the final 's') method to add several columns to an existing Spark dataframe without calling several times `withColumn`. You just need a map `Map[String, Column]`. Given two UDF's for this example `udf1` and `udf2` you could use this new method like this:

```
val dfNew=df.withColumns(Map("newCol1"->udf1(col("oldCol1")),"newCol2"->udf2(col("oldCol2"))))
```

More information on this can be found now at [official doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#withColumns(colsMap:java.util.Map%5BString,org.apache.spark.sql.Column%5D):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame).

Comment: this is awesome, thanks for updating this old question, sure its gonna be very useful for many,

Comment: @Shankar I think this should be the accepted answer now.

Answer (score 69):

AFAIk you need to call `withColumn` twice (once for each new column). But if your udf is computationally expensive, you can avoid to call it twice with storing the "complex" result in a temporary column and then "unpacking" the result e.g. using the `apply` method of column (which gives access to the array element). Note that sometimes it's necessary to cache the intermediate result (to prevent that the UDF is called twice per row during unpacking), sometimes it's not needed. This seems to depend on how spark the optimizes the plan :

```
val myUDf = udf((s:String) => Array(s.toUpperCase(),s.toLowerCase()))

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq("Peter","John")).toDF("name")

val newDf = df
  .withColumn("udfResult",myUDf(col("name"))).cache 
  .withColumn("uppercaseColumn", col("udfResult")(0))
  .withColumn("lowercaseColumn", col("udfResult")(1))
  .drop("udfResult")

newDf.show()
```

gives

```
+-----+---------------+---------------+
| name|uppercaseColumn|lowercaseColumn|
+-----+---------------+---------------+
|Peter|          PETER|          peter|
| John|           JOHN|           john|
+-----+---------------+---------------+
```

With an UDF returning a tuple, the unpacking would look like this:

```
val newDf = df
    .withColumn("udfResult",myUDf(col("name"))).cache
    .withColumn("lowercaseColumn", col("udfResult._1"))
    .withColumn("uppercaseColumn", col("udfResult._2"))
    .drop("udfResult")
```