# How to save the returned values of UDF function into two columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My function `get_data` returns a tuple: two integer values.

```
get_data_udf = udf(lambda id: get_data(spark, id), (IntegerType(), IntegerType()))
```

I need to split them into two columns `val1` and `val2`. How can I do it?

```
dfnew = df \
    .withColumn("val", get_data_udf(col("id")))
```

Should I save the tuple in a column, e.g. `val`, and then split it somehow into two columns. Or is there any shorter way?

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/40962714/1138523

Comment: in scala, you could to `.withColumn("val1", col("val._1")).withColumn("val2", col("val._2"))`, not sure whether this works in pyspark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create structFields in udf in order to access later times.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

get_data_udf = udf(lambda id: get_data(spark, id), 
      StructType([StructField('first', IntegerType()), StructField('second', IntegerType())]))
dfnew = df \
    .withColumn("val", get_data_udf(col("id"))) \
    .select('*', 'val.`first`'.alias('first'), 'val.`second`'.alias('second'))
```

Comment: What is the meaning of `.select('*'`?

Comment: it means all columns.

Comment: Ah, ok. It is necessary to do `drop("val")`, right?

Comment: Not sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

tuple's can be indexed just like lists, so you can add the value for column one as `get_data()[0]` and for the second value in the second column you do `get_data()[1]`

also you can do `v1, v2 = get_data()` and this way assign the returned tuple values to the variables `v1` and `v2`.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136059/getting-one-value-from-a-python-tuple) question here for further clarification.

Comment: If I do `withColumn("val1", get_data_udf(col("id"))[0]).withColumn("val2", get_data_udf(col("id"))[1])`, then I will call `get_data_udf` twice. Isnt'it?

Comment: Also, how can I run `v1, v2 = get_data()`, if I run this function row-wise in the DataFrame?

Comment: put the first in a loop, and append v1 and v2 to your df row by row - that's how it could work!

Comment: Can you please add some example? But the loops are normally not used in distributed programming. Maybe I misunderstood your idea. Therefore the example will be helpful.

Comment: @Markus: If you don't want to run the udf twice then you need to save the result in a separate column temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

For example you have a sample dataframe of one column like below

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(3)).toDF()
df.show()
```

[image]

//Below is a UDF which will return a tuple

```
def tupleFunction(): (Int,Int) = (1,2)
```

//we will create two new column from the above UDF

```
df.withColumn("newCol",typedLit(tupleFunction.toString.replace("(","").replace(")","")
.split(","))).select((0 to 1)
.map(i => col("newCol").getItem(i).alias(s"newColFromTuple$i")):_*).show
```

[image]

Comment: It's scala, no? I would need Python.

Comment: that’s correct. Only tulle function will differ. Apart from that the actual code is spark api. It should work